# Wordpress, style php-generated post

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Good evening,

Im creating a wordpress-site with a self-made template.

I would like to be able to style every singe post with css. This line:

```
<h2 id="post-<?php the_ID();
```

creates a new ID for every post i make, for example `<h2 id="post-1603">`...Is there anyway that I can style, in advance, every post this line will create?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question.  If `the_ID()` creates a unique ID for every post (say "post-12345") are you saying you want the stylesheet to have an a set of styles specifically for `#post-12345` as opposed to any other post?  What actually are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry for beeing unclear, I would like the same set of styles to be applied to every post generated by the php...if possible

Comment: Then you should add a class like "php-generated" and apply your style to this class.

Comment: Are you saying that I should wrap the php in a class of "php-generated"? Would that really work?

Comment: I agree--if you want to style some particular "class" of element then you should just modify the template to include an appropriate class name and add styling for that class in your stylesheet.

Comment: so how do i modify the tmplate to make this line:

<h2 id="post-<?php the_ID();

Into a class?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to style every post individually, then you can style using inline style.

If you styled using the method you specified, your css file size will become very large. It is a bad practise.

So, My suggestion is to use inline style while creating each post.

Comment: Thanks for aswering, ok so there is no way to somehow use the
 
<h2 id="post-<?php the_ID();

in css like #post-(?)...so that every post generated gets the same style?

Comment: Ya. You can't autogenerate css files. If you need you can generate it manually only.

Comment: Well, you can dynamically generate CSS files just fine--there's just no reason you should in this case.